# finding string format specifiers of variable argument list

Tags: c++

I have this Log function that call my logger (spdlog) methods :

```
template<typename... Args>
void Log(const char* fmt,
         const Args&... args)
{
    g_FileLogger->log(fmt, args...);
}
```

I want to change my logger (spdlog, represented by g_FileLoggre) to another logger. Unfortunately, "fmt" strings contain "{}" which are the the placeholder of variables "args". I want to change those "{}" by the correct format specifier (%s, %zu, %d etc...) as with the other loggers, I have to specify the correct format specifier.

Can you give me a quick and safe solution to generate a string that replaces "{}" by the correct format specifier of the variables.

Otherwise, spdlog is a great logging API, but since its API has been broken, we decided to choose another logger, for example in Centos the API is old whereas in Gentoo it is newer and code will not compile.

Comment: Did You try regex replace?

Comment: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt

Answer (score 2):

Create a `format_converter` function

```
template<typename... Args>
std::string format_converter(const char* fmt,
                             const Args&... args)
{...}
```

which parses the fmt string and converts it according to the arguments.

Then modify your function:

```
template<typename... Args>
void Log(const char* fmt,
         const Args&... args)
{
    auto new_fmt = format_converter(fmt, args...);
    new_logger->log( new_fmt, args... );
}
```

---

Edit:

In the `format_converter`,  template functions can be used to convert the types of parameters to strings. For example:

```
template< typename T >
const char* type_string( const T ); // primary template


const char* type_string( const char* ) // overload for c-string
{
    return "%s";
}

template<>
const char* type_string< double >( const double ) // partial specialization for double
{
    return "%d";
}

template<>
const char* type_string< int >( const int ) // partial specialization for int
{
    return "%i";
}

 // .....
```

Comment: I'm not good with templates, can you please give me a simple code for format_converter that uses type_string. Thanks

Comment: @Aminos Did You try the fmt library?

Comment: I don't want to use it because when I tried to use Spdlog (which uses fmt) under Ubuntu, I had to modify the name of a const variable (in an fmt's source file) already taken by a define elsewhere (I don't know where). I don't want to deal with this kind of problem in the app I'm packaging (this is also the reason why I want to use another "stable" logging API other than spdlog, which I like).

Answer (score 1):

Create the `convert_format` function that will replace `{..}` with what you specify. Create a `std::map<std::string, std::string>` object that contains the data for replacing.

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

std::string convert_format(const std::string& format, std::map<std::string, std::string> format_map) {
    string ret;
    for (int x = 0; x != format.size(); ++x)  {
        if (format[x] == '{') {
            std::string key;
            ++x;
            for (; x != format.size(); ++x) {
                if (format[x] == '}') {
                    auto itr = format_map.find(key);
                    if (itr != format_map.end()) {
                        ret += (*itr).second;
                    }
                    break;
                } else {
                    key.push_back(format[x]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            ret.push_back(format[x]);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

And now modifies the `Log` function as:

```
template<typename... Args>
void Log(const char* fmt,
         const Args&... args)
{
    // map that will contain the data.
    std::map<std::string, std::string> format_map;

    // IF you have an args named as number and a string
    // replaces {number} with %d
    format_map["number"] = "%d";

    // for replacing '{string}' with %s
    format_map["string"] = "%s"; // ... and so on

    auto new_fmt = convert_format(std::string(fmt), format_map);
    new_logger->log( new_fmt, args... );
}
```

**EDIT**: I think you need a macro that will pass name and value of the variable to the function `Log`.